# Can't upload image in D-Link "Emergency Room": "Failed to upload image"

Tags: flashing

Whenever I try to upload an image in the D-Link emergency room section, I get the "FAILED TO UPLOAD IMAGE" error, no matter which image I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `curl` command to upload the image.

If you use a Mac, place the firmware .bin file on your desktop and call it `fw.bin`. In the below, replace USERNAME with your computer's username, then run the command in the Terminal.

`curl 192.168.0.101 -F "upload=@/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/fw.bin"`